# Can I use smart switches for my 3-way?

Tags: multiway-switch, smart-switch

I have a 3 way setup and one switch has white black and copper wire and the other one has the same but with a red wire. Can I use smart switches for these? 
Thanks!
Joe

Comment: 3-ways are simple enough once you label them.  But 99.9% are unlabeled, and those are much more complicated.  The info you provided is not sufficient to understand the circuit.  We need to know about all 3 non-grounds per switch, which cables they are grouped into, and the colors of the screws on the switches. Or some photos. [Edit] your question to add the info.

Comment: I am going to have to get some sleep. I will post again tomorrow with pictures. One switch does have a few common wires tied together. With the black and red and copper wire. The other switch has a black white and ground. Thanks for trying. It's 3am and I am having trouble seeing straight. Good night,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a smart 3-way switch can be installed.I have used [this 3-way switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QNZN73T) in the past. Additionally, with the new smart switches, in general, the use for 3-way IMHO is becoming obsolete. Most link to your smart home hub (i.e. Alexa Echo or Google Home) and you simply have to tell it to turn on or off.

If you don't want a 3-way you could also get [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EZV35QU) alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Stop!!!
white black and copper is not a legal 3 way to start with. It is not safe and a code violation.

Yes there some smart switches that can make this right and have some nice features like dimming and 10 seconds fade to off

Lutron majestic? Or maestro has just a switch I have used several times in years past one is a master or controller and the second is a slave or remote.